# Pandas extract data from column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
d={'x':[8,5,6,7],
   'cord':['(3,0)','(2,0)','(6,0)','(1,0)']}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

I would like to create df['y'] which will have the first 'cord' value and shift to get index value.

```
    cord  x  y
0  (3,0)  8  1     #Index 3, First value in (1,0)
1  (2,0)  5  6     #Index 2, First value in (6,0)
2  (6,0)  6  NaN   #Index 6, does not exist, NaN
3  (1,0)  7  2     #Index 1, First value (1,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate column, which is the first element of cord

```
df['cord1'] = df.cord.map( lambda x: x.split(',')[0].split('(')[-1]).map(int)
df
#    cord  x  cord1
#0  (3,0)  8      3
#1  (2,0)  5      2
#2  (6,0)  6      6
#3  (1,0)  7      1
```

This might look confusing, but it simply splits the string '(a,b)' twice, first on `','` , and then on `'('`.  Finally, it casts the remaining string ,`'a'` ,  to an integer.

Now use the cord1 column to make the y column

```
df['y'] =  df.cord1[ df.cord1.values].values
```

being careful to pass the values. Now drop the cord1 column

```
df.drop( labels='cord1', axis=1, inplace=True)

#df
#    cord  x   y
#0  (3,0)  8   1
#1  (2,0)  5   6
#2  (6,0)  6 NaN
#3  (1,0)  7   2
```

Comment: I had to make a slight adjustment, where y column is created, ```df['y'] = ...``` is the proper syntax I believe. If instead one does, ```df.y = ...``` it creates a hidden attribute ```df.y```, which wont show up when you print ```df```, at least in pandas 0.16.1.

Comment: what if df.cord1.values sometimes produces an IndexError (the Index doesn't exist). I am using an iterrows() and catching the IndexError exception which works but I don't think its the most efficient. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid that

Comment: Hmm, you are looping over ```df.cord1.values``` and indexing the dataframe on each iteration ? Try indexing with an array, even if you are indexing a single element. For example ```df.cord1[[6]]``` returns ```np.nan``` however, ```df.cord1[6]``` will throw an error.